# Problema con mi background no se completa al full con el with

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buenas tengo una duda al agregar una librería de particulas el fondo de mi web no agarra el 100% de el fondo se queda como a la mitad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y yo quisiera que sea completo el backgroud.

les comparto la liga donde tengo el código de todo.

ejemplo quiero que ocupe todo el fondo o background como esta imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta el codigo:
https://wormhole.app/p9L0K#-TS7i_KKrOB5MzRw0RZtHw

Comment: Debes incluir un [mcve] en tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Disculpa ejemplo como que lo que trato de decir que en la primera imagen se queda a la mitad de donde dice skills y quiero que ocupe todo el fondo blanco, no se si me di a entender.

Comment: No podemos hacer nada si no agregar tu código con la que estás trabajando. Con unas fotos no es suficiente. Es necesario que leas bien [ask] para que hagas una buena pregunta y que podamos ayudarte. SIN TU CÓDIGO ES DIFÍCIL

Comment: el código esta en el link que pase esta todo, lo pase todo ya que no se donde viene el error y por eso no puedo pasar solo el trozo de codigo ya que no se donde viene el error

Comment: aparte mandar el código me da error ya que es demasiado por eso lo pase por un link para compartir mi proyecto

Comment: No necesitas todo el proyecto, sólo un [mcve]. Debes ser capaz de aislar la parte relativa al background y la estructura básica en HTML.